# Read "Blocked Content" node attribute from XML document using R

Tags: r, xml, attributes, nodes

I am fairly new to XML language. I am trying to access an XML document in R to analyze it, modify it and then save an updated version of the XML.

This is how I am getting the document in R

```
XMLDocument <- xmlTreeParse(ForecastSummary, useInternalNodes = F)
```

This is what the document looks like in R

```
<topic id="ID8980f110-d410-4430-9a63-2c05d93e86cd" xmlns:xt="urn:xpressauthor:trackchanges">
 <prolog>
  <Id>735256</Id>
 </prolog>
 <title>TEXT</title>
 <body>
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
  <p id="ID1fba1056-60d5-4c60-adec-b1fc5a8967be">TEXT</p>
  <h1>Global Performance</h1>
  <p id="ID6ff0b578-0196-487f-a7a9-f5912e29b5c0">TEXT</p>
  <image imagedef="picture" href="Chart_A1_86_88.png" width="586" height="207" widthdpi="96" heightdpi="96"/>
  <image imagedef="picture" href="Chart_A2_86_88.png" width="586" height="369" widthdpi="96" heightdpi="96"/>
  <p id="IDc4a8a42e-193f-4b91-ba45-f5a9baa9bc3d">TEXT</p>
  <p id="ID5895e97e-54d7-430f-9a0b-55674d13bb88"/>
  <p id="IDbc1b5455-8cca-4fa3-b51d-a0a3c3ce9ad5"/>
  <p id="IDd9dc6637-facd-45c3-a406-79fd3fe6342f"/>
  <p id="IDf299a3d8-8be1-4aad-8428-e622e52ec3ae"/>
  <p id="ID0f11178c-7d89-4341-8853-86fbbdb80766"/>
  <p id="ID8d08978a-2704-4a05-89a9-b13ae2194a3f"/>
  <p id="ID43ba5a8b-f530-4532-a29c-d2b9e6072b65"/>
 </body>
 <attachments/>
</topic>

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLDocumentContent"

$dtd
$external
NULL

$internal
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "DTDList"

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLDocument"         "XMLAbstractDocument"
```

However when I open the XML document in Internet Explorer. I get the following pop-up message:

> Internet Explorer Restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.

When I click on "Allow blocked content", the "image" and "topic" nodes attributes look very different:

```
<?XpressproductLine="gentitle-article" accessMode="Revise"?>      
<topic id="ID8980f110-d410-4430-9a63-2c05d93e86cd" cmsId="qpp://assets/735256?collectionpath=XXXXXX&name=XXXXX.xml" cmsReviewOptions="TrackChanges=true,AllowToggleTrackChanges=false">    
  <prolog>  
    <Id>735256</Id>
  </prolog>
  <title>TEXT</title>
  <body>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <p id="ID1fba1056-60d5-4c60-adec-b1fc5a8967be">TEXT</p>
    <h1>TEXT</h1>
    <p id="ID6ff0b578-0196-487f-a7a9-f5912e29b5c0">TEXT</p>
    <image imagedef="picture" href="qpp://assets/735902?collectionpath=XXXX&name=Chart_A1_86_88.png" width="586" height="207" widthdpi="96" heightdpi="96"/>
    <image imagedef="picture" href="qpp://assets/735903?collectionpath=Home/World Industry/Industry Outlook/Health and Social Work&name=Chart_A2_86_88.png" width="586" height="369" widthdpi="96" heightdpi="96"/>
    <p id="IDc4a8a42e-193f-4b91-ba45-f5a9baa9bc3d">TEXT</p>
    <p id="ID5895e97e-54d7-430f-9a0b-55674d13bb88"/>
    <p id="IDbc1b5455-8cca-4fa3-b51d-a0a3c3ce9ad5"/>
    <p id="IDd9dc6637-facd-45c3-a406-79fd3fe6342f"/>
    <p id="IDf299a3d8-8be1-4aad-8428-e622e52ec3ae"/>
    <p id="ID0f11178c-7d89-4341-8853-86fbbdb80766"/>
    <p id="ID8d08978a-2704-4a05-89a9-b13ae2194a3f"/>
    <p id="ID43ba5a8b-f530-4532-a29c-d2b9e6072b65"/>
  </body>       
  <attachments/>
</topic>
```

Anyway, why do I get this "blocked content" in R?

Comment: It's not R, it's IE the one throwing that message. Try FF as a test.

Comment: Where is the R code? What does the final XML look like, not in a web browser but as a raw text file? `<?XpressproductLine="gentitle-article" accessMode="Revise"?>` is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find out how to actually get this "blocked content" in R but was able to "hard code" it in the R script. The platform I am uploading it to was then able to ingest it without problem.